# When running Hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode, what directory should I use for hadoop.tmp.dir?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configuration, hadoop, hbase

By default, Hadoop sets hadoop.tmp.dir to your /tmp folder.  This is a problem, because /tmp gets wiped out by Linux when you reboot, leading to this lovely error from the JobTracker :

```
2012-10-05 07:41:13,618 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 0 time(s).    
...    
2012-10-05 07:41:22,636 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 9 time(s).
2012-10-05 07:41:22,643 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: problem cleaning system directory: null
java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:767)
```

The only way I've found to fix this is to reformat your name node, which rebuilds the /tmp/hadoop-root folder, which of course gets wiped out again when you reboot.

So I went ahead and created a folder called /hadoop_temp and gave all users read/write access to it.  I then set this property in my core-site.xml :

```
 <property>
          <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
          <value>file:///hadoop_temp</value>
 </property>
```

When I re-formatted my namenode, Hadoop seemed happy, giving me this message :

```
12/10/05 07:58:54 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory file:/hadoop_temp/dfs/name has been successfully formatted.
```

However, when I looked at /hadoop_temp, I noticed that the folder was empty.  And then when I restarted Hadoop and checked my JobTracker log, I saw this :

```
2012-10-05 08:02:41,988 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 0 time(s).
...
2012-10-05 08:02:51,010 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8020. Already tried 9 time(s).
2012-10-05 08:02:51,011 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: problem cleaning system directory: null
java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

And when I checked my namenode log, I saw this :

```
2012-10-05 08:00:31,206 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory /opt/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/file:/hadoop_temp/dfs/name does not exist.
2012-10-05 08:00:31,212 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /opt/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/file:/hadoop_temp/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
```

So, clearly I didn't configure something right.  Hadoop still expects to see its files in the /tmp folder even though I set hadoop.tmp.dir to /hadoop_temp in core-site.xml.  What did I do wrong?  What's the accepted "right" value for hadoop.tmp.dir?

Bonus question : what should I use for hbase.tmp.dir?

System info :

Ubuntu 12.04,
Apache Hadoop .20.2,
Apache HBase .92.1

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Harsh on the Hadoop mailing list for helping me with this.  To quote him :

"On 0.20.x or 1.x based releases, do not use a file:/// prefix for hadoop.tmp.dir."

I took out the file:// prefix, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Also with Hbase 0.94* you will have to specify

`<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>`